# Append the end of one line to the start of the next with sed

Tags: sed

I'm looking for `sed` only solutions for the following:

Corrupted Input:

```
A 123 dgbsdgsbg
A 345 gsgsdgdgs A 23
2 afaffaaf
A 324 fsgdggsdg A 345 avsa
fasf
```

Expected output:

```
A 123 dgbsdgsbg
A 345 gsgsdgdgs
A 232 afaffaaf
A 324 fsgdggsdg
A 345 avsafasf
```

How can the trailing `A [0-9].*` be appended to the start of the next line. So far I have:

```
$ sed -r 's/ (A [0-9]+.*)/\n\1/' file
A 123 dgbsdgsbg
A 345 gsgsdgdgs
A 23
2 afaffaaf
A 324 fsgdggsdg
A 345 avsa
fasf
```

Comment: Et tu, [sudo_O](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1562/sed?userid=1066031)?

Comment: @devnull this is the kind of problem where my brain switches to `awk` beyond substitutions and a few other tricks my `sed` knowledge doesn't travel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed -r '$!N;s/ (A[^\n]*)\n/\n\1/;P;D' file
```

Comment: Care to explain `$!N` and `P;D`?

Comment: @sudo_O `$!N` means if not end-of-file append a newline (`\n`) and the next line to the current line in the pattern space. `P` means print upto the first newline or end of the pattern space which ever comes first and `D` delete upto and including the first newline or the upto the end of the pattern space which ever comes first. `D` causes the automatic reading in of the next line if a newline exists in the pattern space before it is deleted to be suspended until no newline in found.

Answer (score 3):

This can be an option:

```
$ sed -r ':a;$!N;s/ (A [0-9]+.*)\n(.*)/\n\1\2/;ta;P;D' file
A 123 dgbsdgsbg
A 345 gsgsdgdgs
A 232 afaffaaf
A 324 fsgdggsdg
A 345 avsafasf
```

It is an adaption of the last example from [How to match newlines in sed](http://backreference.org/2009/12/23/how-to-match-newlines-in-sed/):

```
sed ':begin;$!N;s/FOO\nBAR/FOOBAR/;tbegin;P;D'
# if a line ends in FOO and the next starts with BAR, join them
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you try:

```
sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\([0-9]\)\n\([0-9]\)/\1\2/;ta' -e 'P;D'
```

Example:

```
$ cat input
abc 123
456
def
123
ghi 123
jkl 456
789
$ sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\([0-9]\)\n\([0-9]\)/\1\2/;ta' -e 'P;D' input
abc 123456
def
123
ghi 123
jkl 456789
```

EDIT: You modified the example in the question later.  For your modified input, try:

```
$ sed -e 's/ \(A .*\)/\n\1/' -e :a -e '$!N;s/\n\([^A]\)/\1/;ta' -e 'P;D' newinput
A 123 dgbsdgsbg
A 345 gsgsdgdgs
A 232 afaffaaf
A 324 fsgdggsdg
A 345 avsafasf
```